# matplotlib: AxesSubplot object has no attribute tick_params

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, plot

I am trying to make a simple plot using matplotlib imported through pylab: 
   from pylab import *

```
list_of_files=[('EXP001.txt','EXP001'),('EXP002.txt','EXP002'),('EXP003.txt','EXP003'),('EXP004.txt','EXP004')]

datalist = [ ( loadtxt(filename), label ) for filename, label in list_of_files ]

fig=figure()
ax=fig.add_subplot(111)

for data, label in datalist:
line,= loglog( data[:,0], data[:,2], ls='-', marker='.', label=label)

ax.tick_params(axis='x', reset=True, which='minor', labelbottom='on')

legend()
title("EXP001 Simulations")
xlabel("k in $h/Mpc$ ")
ylabel("$P(k)$")
savefig('./pyprueba.png',dpi=200)
show()
```

But I keep getting the error :

```
File "pyplot.PS.py", line 13, in <module>
ax.tick_params(axis='x', reset=True, which='minor', labelbottom='on')
AttributeError: 'AxesSubplot' object has no attribute 'tick_params'
```

I have extracted parts of this code from examples on this website and official documentation examples, so I really don't know what is the problem here.

Comment: What version are you using? MPL v1.2.0 works for me.

Comment: Yeah, sadly I have a quite old version: 0.99.3. But I am in my institute, I would have to ask the administrator to update it.

Comment: `matplotlib` is quite easy to install locally, `python setup.py install --prefix=/where/ever/you/want` and then add the correct paths to you pythonpath.

Comment: I already did that and added the local install path to my PYTHONPATH using export in my .bashrc file. But when I type matplotlib.__version__ in python, I still get version 0.99.3